# Rails 3: Best practices for saving models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

When should I save my models in rails? and who should be responsible for calling save, the model itself, or the caller?

Lets say I have (public)methods like `udpate_points`, `update_level`, etc. in my user model. There are 2 options:

1. The model/method is responsible for calling save . So each method will just call  `self.save`.
2. The caller is responsible for calling save. So each method only updates the attributes but the caller calls `user.save` when it's done with the user.

The tradeoffs are fairly obvious: 
In option *#1* the model is guaranteed to save, but we call save multiple times per transaction. 
In option *#2* we call save only once per transaction, but the caller has to make sure to call save. For example `team.leader.update_points` would require me to call `team.leader.save` which is somewhat non-intuitive. This can get even more complicated if I have multiple methods operating on the same model object.

Adding a more specific info as per request: 
update level looks at how many points the users has and updates the level of the user. The function also make a call to the facebook api to notify it that the user has achieved an new level, so I might potently execute it as a background job.

Comment: The best implementation completely depends on what the methods "update_points" and "update_level" do.  What parameters are they passed and what do they do with those parameters?

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way of implementing stuff like this is using attr_accessors and model hooks.  Here is an example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :pts

  after_validation :adjust_points, :on => :update

  def adjust_points
    if self.pts
      self.points = self.pts / 3 #Put whatever code here that needs to be executed
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your controller you do something like this:

```
def update
  User.find(params[:id]).update_attributes!(:pts => params[:points])
end
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but I'm not sure that it solves my problem... You are essentially just calling the method every time you update the class, but you still have to call update. My question is when do you have to call save/update.... On a different note- adjust_points is going to get called everytime an field gets updated (not only points), so I'm not sure why you would use this.

Comment: Well, yes `adjust_points` gets called every time, but you can see there is a conditional that stops the execution if the attr_accessor isn't set.