# Is it ideal to perform save in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Where is the best way to perform save. I created a logger method which will log everything what admin users did.

```
def log(params_here={})
   initialized_model = Model.new(with_proper_parameters_here)
   initialized_model.save
end
```

I was thinking if I will put this to `model` or on `lib`. So the question is, is it ideally to put this method on `model`? Or I will just put it on `lib`? And what is the cause/advatages/disadvantages when I do it on model/lib?

UPDATE:

I also found the following but it didn't satisfy my question.

1. [Rails 3: Best practices for saving models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336163/rails-3-best-practices-for-saving-models)
2. https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/top-10-mistakes-that-rails-programmers-make

Comment: On my case, I am always doing it on lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look like a model, so really has no place in the `models` directory. If it's an external utility that is responsible for constructing a model, then `lib` would be a good place for it though I'd also avoid defining it in the global namespace especially for such a commonly used term like `log`. I'm also a bit confused on why this method is called `log` as it doesn't seem to be doing any logging.

Personally I'd put it in lib, or more likely wrap it in a builder object which might go with other service objects I often have declared in `app/services`. Hard to say without more context on how, where, and why it's being used.

And why not simplify?

```
def log(params_here={})
   Model.create(with_proper_parameters_here)
end
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for helping me to decide. I'll accept your answer. Thanks!